# Searchbar an array of Dictionaries Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uisearchbar, searchbar

I've got the situation where I'm kind of stuck. 
Simplifying, my task is to parse JSON to (for example) UITableView and to filter it through native SearchBar.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "title":"Two",
   "image":"Two.png"

    }
```

...etc

After parsing I get an Array of Dictionaries which looks like this (decomposed to have deeper understanding)

```
imagesArray = [["title":"Two", "image":"Two.png"],["title":"Three Four", "image":"ThreeFour.png"],["title":"Five", "image":"Five.png"]]
```

I've to filter using the "title" name.
Though, I can't really figure it out how to use native SearchBar filtering through the Array of Dicts, but I know there are ways.

Or if my whole concept of parsing to an Array of Dicts is wrong feel free to correct me and show any of the different methods :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the JSON into an array of dicts, however, I would recommend parsing the data into an array of codable structs or classes like so.

```
let json = """
[
{
"title":"Two",
"image":"Two.png"

}
]
"""

struct Item: Codable {
    var title, image: String
}

if let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        var items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: jsonData)

    } catch {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

class del: NSObject,UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    }
}
```

Once you have the array of objects you can filter them into a new array which you use as the data for a UITableView in the textDidChange UISearchBarDelegate method like this.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let filteredItems = items.filter { (item) in
        item.title
            .lowercased()
            .contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
func searchFor(_ chars: String) -> [[String : String]] {
    return imagesArray.filter { ($0["title"]?.range(of: chars, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil) }
}


print(searchFor("th")) // [["title": "Three Four", "image": "ThreeFour.png"]]
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.